# cocos 2d v3 ccPhysicsCollisionBegin access returned bool

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I need to access the returned BOOL from this method:

```
- (BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair typeA:(CCNode *)nodeA typeB:(CCNode *)nodeB {

     return YES; 
}
```

I need this because I want to do specific things when 2 object collide, but if I use

```
    BOOL result = [self ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *) typeA:(CCNode *) typeB:(CCNode *)];
```

I am not sure on what I have to pass, i think typeA and typeB are the 2 physicsbody but I have no idea regarding on what give instead of (CCPhysicsCollisionPair *).

Can you help me please?

Or in another way I could do the same things passing 2 integer to the method or anyway accessing 2 integer that I created before in another method, but i think i can't do that.

Comment: This particular return value isn't meant for you, it's for the physics engine. If you return NO it will ignore the collision.  Nor should you call this method by yourself. 

You need to determine inside the method whether the two bodies in question did collide, and then run whatever code you need to run.

Comment: Ok but I need to use 2 integer that i set in another method, how can I do that?

Comment: Okay sorry, I am a noob :-/ simply I had to declare the 2 variables in the implementation of my class, so now i can use them without any problem.